# Office 365 Sharepoint online log files

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I would like to know if something went wrong in sharepoint online 2013 where can I see the log messages? In sharepoint 2013 (not the online one) I could see the log messages in log folder which is in 15. But I dont know where to look in sharepoint 2013 online.

Thank you for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean external data logs?

You can use this option through Sharepoint Admin Centre>BCS, depending on your plan.
You can check if it's available for you here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx